# Instruct LINQ to Entities to Generate Oracle Compatible SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a linq to entities query (EF 4.3)

```
var query = from item in db.TableTest
            select item.VAL;
```

which translates to this SQL statement

```
SELECT
"Extent1"."VAL" AS "VAL"
FROM "dbo"."TEST_TABLE" "Extent1"
```

The database is **Oracle**.

When I execute the query I get the message that the datatable does not exist. The problem is the (**"dbo"**) part. If i remove it and execute this query directly (not through LINQ but through an oracleconnection etc)

```
SELECT
"Extent1"."VAL" AS "VAL"
FROM "TEST_TABLE" "Extent1"
```

then everything is ok. I get values back.

**How can I instruct Linq To Entities to output Oracle compatible SQL**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after asking, i found a way to solve my problem

I had this POCO class

```
[Table("TEST_TABLE")]
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key, Column("VAL")]
    public string key_valye { get; set; }
}
```

The generated sql injected the "dbo". When i changed the table attribute to

```
 [Table("TEST_TABLE", Schema="ATT")]
```

This generated the "ATT"."TEST_TABLE" instead, which was actually the correct sql.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an entity model, make sure you correctly set the DDL generation template.

Also, you can remove the `dbo` for the database schema name to match your actual DB.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am not allowed to alter anything in the database actually. I am an oracle newbie too.

I don't have an entity model. I use POCO classes. I found that by annotating my entity class with the [Table("TABLE_NAME", Schema="SCHEMA_NAME")] attribute, i solved the problem

Comment: @Saysmaster I didn't knew if you were using code first or model first approach (you did not specified). In my answer, I assumed you were using an entity model, so I show how to modify the `Schema` property of the model. As you're actually using code first, you'll have to manually change the `Schema` property in the attributes, as you found by yourself.

Comment: I can't autogenerate an Entity Model from this database for some reasons. It is mostly due to the fact that the generator cannot find the primary keys on the tables. So I tried to create POCO classes and map them manually to the tables I wanted...